# How do I trace input parameters to an .exe?

Tags: windows, iis, asp-classic, exe, trace

I have an application (IIS ASP) that sends input parameters to an another applications executable file.

How would I go about finding (in a trace)  this executable input parameters that was passed to it from the other application?

ps
I do not have the source code available for both the asp and the .exe yip this is the fun black box world of an Enterprise Developer dealing with an Oracle Solution...

Comment: Re: *I do not have the source code available for both the asp and the .exe*.  This cannot be true.  In ASP, the .asp file is the source.  If it's your server, you have the source.  Which means, the easiest way to solve the problem is to call the .exe via a layer that logs the parameters in a place where you can get them.

Comment: Lol ok I don't have access to the server. It is not my server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you just create a basic console app with the same name as the .exe which writes its args to disk?

So your IIS app calls this app instead.

Answer (score 0):

[Process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) shows the command line parameters of all running processes